# OneNote local copy of web notebook?

Tags: microsoft-onenote

Does OneNote 2010 maintain a local copy of a web notebook?  If so, where?  I'd like to ensure my notebooks get backed up

Comment: can an admin move this to superuser?

Answer (score 10):

OneNote maintains a local copy of every web notebook in a cache file called `OneNoteOfflineCache.onecache`

You can check where it is located / change the location by going to **File** -> **Options** -> **Save & Backup** -> **Cache File Location**. It **isn't** a normal OneNote Notebook file, i.e. if you would need to restore notebooks from the cache file, you would need to paste it back into OneNote's cache location (which would overwrite more recent changes than the backups) and then let OneNote sync.

An easier way (especially for restoring specific things) would be to use OneNote's backup feature (look at the **Save & Backup** settings to it's settings). Here, the notebooks are saved as any other notebooks (i.e. can simply be moved around & double-clicked to open).

Comment: This way is good, but there always contain **time tags**. For example, the `test.one` would be saved as `test.one (On 08-06-14).one`

Answer (score 3):

You can actually:

- Right click the notebook click on "Properties"
- Click on "Change Location". Go to your local folder, and click select.
   The current Notebook will be automatically located to a local folder. It is actually just copied everything to a new location, and the original will not be deleted from the server.
- Open the notebook from the web again.
   Now you have 2 same Notebooks. One is local, the other is synchronized.
- Just close the local one if you just want it as a backup. You can find it later in your local folder.